# mxGraph loading from XML but cant insert element after it is loaded

Tags: javascript, xml, mxgraph

here is the code

```
onSave(){
var encoder = new mxCodec();
var result = encoder.encode(this.graph.getModel());
this.dataToSave = mxUtils.getXml(result);
}


     onLoad(){
    
    var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(this.dataToSave);
    var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
    codec.decode(doc.documentElement, this.graph.getModel());
    }
```

but at the end it wont add something like this
note:it will add it before the load button is clicked

```
this.graph.insertVertex(this.g7, 'c3', this.getGroup(1), 95, 90, 110, 50,'child');
```

Comment: Can be problem with context(this.graph) 
Can you provide an online demo(codePen etc)?